# Comparison test, with one negative term?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can I use the Comparison Test for a series when only the first term of the series is negative?

Comment: Yes. But why?${}$

Comment: You can ignore any finite number of terms.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. If only the first term of the series is negative, and all the rest of the terms are positive, then consider using the Comparison Test for $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k\quad \text{ and } \quad \sum_{k=2}^\infty b_k$$

Comment: okay thanks for the answer